# Run bash through discord api

Tags: python, bots, discord

I want to make a bot that runs bash commands through the discord api with a checker against a file called admin.json that would run through discord's API running bash commands on my vps server so I don't have to logon each time through ssh. I want to do this over discord specifically.

I tried researching LIKE EVERYWHERE.. 
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.MessageType
This was the closet I have gotten to about what I need: To return the message.content identifier. I want to be able to access my vps server over discord so I don't have to login each time through ssh.

````py
import discord
import sys
import os
import json
import subprocess
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

t = "<token here>"

with open("admin.json", "r") as admin:
    admin = json.load(admin)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bash bot is online')

@client.command()
async def on_message(ctx, arg1):
    if str(ctx.author.id) in(admin):
        command = ctx.message.content #this for some reason fails
        cmd = subprocess.getoutput(command)
        await ctx.send(command)
        print(str(ctx.message.content)) #even this one fails :(
    else:
        pass
        await ctx.send("You don't have permission to use this command!" + "\n" + "<" + "@" + str(ctx.author.id) + ">")


client.run(t, bot=True)```

Should be able to run with any args so if there is a space between a bash command it shouldn't break the bot like:
```wget https://google.com``` <- Should not break the discord bot
My most common error message:
```File "bot.py", line 23, in run
    print(message.content)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'
````

Comment: I think it's something to do with str(ctx.message.content) but I want to integrate that into subprocess.getoutput() Function in some way.

Comment: Where can I register as the user "admi"  on your server?

Comment: The line with the error shown does not exist in the code you have shared `print(message.content)`

Comment: @KlausD You need to give me your discord first.

Comment: @IainShelvington I mean ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'``` was my most common problem, ignore the line 23 because I was changing the program too many times and I had too many error messages to deal with. The most common of which was converting to string from ctx.content so that variable can be used to run commands.

Comment: @KlausD. The admin.json file would look somthing like this: ```["DISCORDUSERIDHERE"]```

Comment: Do you want to be using `ctx.content` instead of `ctx.message.content`?

Comment: I have tried that, It's the same thing but I need to convert the `ctx.message.content` to string and use it in the subprocess.output function which doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `check` to handle checking the ids. I'm not sure where your problem with `ctx.message` is coming from, I suspect you had some code that is assigning to it.

```
with open("admin.json", "r") as admin:
    admin = [int(x) for x in json.load(admin)]

def is_any_user(ids):
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.message.author.id in ids
    return commands.check(predicate)

@is_any_user(admin)
@client.command(name="run")
async def run_command(ctx, *, command_string):
    output = subprocess.getoutput(command_string)
    await ctx.send(output)

@run_command.error
async def run_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send(f"You don't have permission, {ctx.author.mention}")
    else:
        raise error
```